# How to format JSON dates with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have an HTML `<input type="date" name="departing" />` which returns for example the date in the following format: `2021-11-07`

When I forward this variable to my handlebars, it is being displayed as follows:

```
Mon Nov 08 2021 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

I would like to have it displayed as:

```
07/11/2021
```

I tried formatting it with **date-fns** like this:

```
departing = format(parseISO(departing.getDate()), "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

But then my handlebar shows: `"Invalid Date"`

I am so confused. Any ideas on how to get that date to be displayed in the 07/11/2021
format?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all create a date object**

```
const newDate = new Date();
```

**Now you can manipulate code to  get answer whatever you want**

```
var outputDate = newDate .getDate() + "/" +  (newDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + 
newDate.getFullYear();
```

**Output will be looks like 01/11/2021**

Answer (score 0):

Well you could go as simple as using #getDate(), #getMonth() and #getFullYear() methods separately then displaying them in the order you'd like like so:

```js
const date = new Date(departing);
const day = date.getDate();
const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
const year = date.getFullYear();

console.log(`${day}/${month}/${year}`);
```

Hope it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by several ways

method 1:-

```
let n = new Date()
console.log(n.toLocaleDateString("en-US")
output=== 31/9/2021
```

method 2 :- get separate values and merge

```
let n = new Date()
console.log(n.getDate()+"/"+n.getMonth()+"/"+n.getFullYear())
output=== 31/9/2021
```